# Align header logo and text side by side (UPDATED, HTML5 / CSS)

Tags: html, css, header, tags

I am pretty new to HTML5, and my book does not go into full detail on how to use the  tag. So, what I am trying to do is align my image and text (h1 tag) side by side in the header. I have tried using different class types (e.g. class="top" / "left"), experimenting with inline and block values in the CSS file. And nothing seems to work. My heading remains pasted in the middle of my page (as if it were in the article tag).

Answer (score 0):

So I noticed you are inserting the image with both `img` in html and in CSS with background. So you'll have to decide one or the other. I went with the html and was able to work something out with flexbox. You can adjust the `padding-left` on your `h1` if there's too much separation (sorry for the cat, it was just an image I had in another project, kind of funny with the Metallica). Also your `img.floatright` rule is not correct, you would just want to have `img { float:right}` but I went with flexbox instead of floats.

```css
header {
    background-color: #e0287a;
    height: 150px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "times new roman", arial verdana;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="flex"><img height="150 width="250" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg" alt="The band"><h1
    class="h1">METALLICA</h1></div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding display grid with auto in the first column and 1fr for the rest like this:

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  display: grid;
  background-color: red;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <img height="150" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/766360293953802240/kt0hiSmv.jpg" alt="The band" />
  <h1 class="h1">METALLICA</h1>
</header>
```